# Visual Basic Two Panels Grow Fullscreen?

Tags: vb.net, layout, size, panel

I just feel awkward when making these Layout as shown ([Preview Link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8961569/misc/vb-layout-panel-neeedhelp.png))

I have 4-panels.
Red Panel is the outer. I use a FlowLayout.
Black Panel is the inner Panel i use normal panel. 
Then, I have Green Panel which is actually  a new container for Blue Panel.

Now, my questions are....

1. What are the solutions if, I want to make Panel-4 Grow (to
   stretch) until the edge (right) of the screen.
2. If I use a TableLayout Panel as a base Panel for Panel-4 &
   Panel-3 is that appropriate? BUt If I apply Dock : FIll for that
   TableLayout, it seems only stretching the vertical size only,
   instead of all (V & H) size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the outer red panel, Have one panel dock left, then do a split panel that fills the right and then modify the settings on how the upper panel (panel 1 property of the split panel) grows. You would basically say that the bottom panel (panel 2 of the split panel) is the fixed panel.